# ldap query error handling

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I am querying LDAP for a user `HomeDirectory`, which I am able to do fine and write it to a textbox.  How do I handle errors when that user doesn't exist in LDAP?

```
If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
     MsgBox("Please enter a Network ID")
     TextBox2.Focus()
     Exit Sub
End If

Dim yourUserName As String = TextBox2.Text
Dim ADSearch As New DirectorySearcher()

Dim de As DirectoryEntry = GetDirectoryEntry()
ADSearch.SearchRoot = de
ADSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" & yourUserName & ")"
'ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("homedirectory")

Dim ADResult As SearchResult = ADSearch.FindOne()
Dim ADEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(ADResult.Path)

TextBox1.Text = (ADEntry.Properties("homedirectory").Value.ToString)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just check the `ADResult`, and then process accordingly?

```
Dim result As SearchResult = ADSearch.FindOne()

If result Is Nothing Then
     Return "Not a valid Active Directory Account"
Else
    Dim ADEntry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(ADResult.Path)
    TextBox1.Text = (ADEntry.Properties("homedirectory").Value.ToString)
End If
```

If you want to handle lower level LDAP errors, just wrap your search code in a `Try`...`Catch`.